# Python: parse VARIANT (?)

Tags: python, variant

I have to read a file in python that uses [Microsoft `VARIANT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380072%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (I think - I really don't know much about Microsoft code :S). **Basically I want to know if there are python packages that can do this for me.**

To explain - the file I'm trying to read is just a whole bunch of `{ 2-byte integer, <data> }` repeated over and over, where the 2-byte integer specifies what the `<data>` is.

The 2-byte integer corresponds to the Microsoft data types in VARIANT: `VT_I2`, `VT_I4`, etc, and based on the type I can write code to read in and coerce `<data>` to an appropriate Python object.

My current attempt is along the following lines:

```
while dtype = file.read(2):
    value = None

    # translate dtype (I've put in VT_XX myself to match up with Microsoft)
    if dtype == VT_I2:
        value = file.read(2)
    elif dtype == VT_I4:
        value = file.read(4)
    # ... and so on for other types

    # append value to the list of values

# return the values we read
return values
```

The thing is, I'm having trouble working out how to convert some of the bytes to the appropriate Python object (for example `VT_BSTR`, `VT_DECIMAL`, `VT_DATE`). However before I try further, I'd like to know **if there are any existing python packages that do this logic for me (i.e. take in a file object/bytes and parse it into a set of python objects, be they float, int, dates, strings, ...).**

It just seems like this is a fairly common thing to do.
However, I've been having difficulty looking for packages to do it because not knowing anything about Microsoft code, I don't have the terminology to do the appropriate googling. (**If it is relevant, I am running LINUX**).

Comment: I'm assuming this is meant to be pseudocode, since `while dtype = file.read(2)` is not legal python.

Comment: Have you tried hachoir (https://bitbucket.org/haypo/hachoir/wiki/Home)? Works on linux and has support for some MS file types. Might be worth a look in case your particular format is covered.

Comment: [OleFileIO_PL](http://www.decalage.info/python/olefileio)

Comment: @ephemient - I am currently using OleFileIO_PL, but it doesn't cover parsing the streams as I have described here (the file type I am trying to parse is a little bit non-standard). The file type is ZVI - a microscope file format. It is encoded as a OLE object (hence OleFileIO_PL), but the streams are just endless `{2-byte-integer-which-is-thetype, data}` one after the other so the usual `getproperties` from `OleFileIO_PL won't do; hence me trying to write my own parser.

Comment: @azhrei - thanks, will have a look at Hachoir. Fingers crossed!

Answer (score 0):

The win32com package in [pywin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/) will do just that for you. The documentation is quite underwhelming, but there's a lot variant.html included explaining the basic use and a lot of tutorials and references online.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I am using Linux, and `pywin32` is not compatible with Linux (because it needs Windows-only module `_winreg`). Is there a Linux alternative?

Comment: I have the same issue, any solution?